# Pyspark UDF getting error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

I am running a code using a pyspark UDF to score a dataframe using a pickled sklearn model. This seemed to work with no issues in Python 2.7 until I changed the engine to Python 3.6. Also this seems to be happening only when the UDF script is run (distributed mode), but sklearn is working fine when ran outside the UDF.

I am getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` whenever I try to `.show()` the dataframe, or in another instance when I try to write the dataframe into the database. See script below:

```
import pickle
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = spark.sql("""SELECT * from database.table_for_scoring""")

## Load pickle file (scikit-learn trained model)
model_rdd_pkl = sc.binaryFiles("final_model.pkl")
model_rdd_data = model_rdd_pkl.collect()

ms_model = pickle.loads(model_rdd_data[0][1])
broadcast_ms_model = sc.broadcast(ms_model)

def predict(*cols):
  prediction = broadcast_ms_model.value.predict_proba((cols,))
  return float(prediction[0,1])

predict_udf = udf(predict, DoubleType())

feature_list = ['feature_a', 'feature_b', 'feature_c']
df_scored = df.withColumn("ms_score", predict_udf(*feature_list))

df_scored.show()
```

Below is the detailed error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.showString. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
> in stage 1.0 (TID 4, dlxwnr15n4120.globetel.com, executor 1):
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
> process()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
> serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in dump_stream
> self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream
> for obj in iterator:   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 209, in _batched
> for item in iterator:   File "", line 1, in    File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in 
> return lambda *a: f(*a)   Engine, line 2, in predict   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 108, in value
> self._value = self.load(self._path)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 99, in load
> return pickle.load(f) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Things I tried:

1. Changed both PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to "/usr/local/bin/python3"
2. Retrained and pickled the sklearn model in Python 3, in the same sklearn version the engine is using, but still doesn't work

Could it be that the executors are not seeing the sklearn package? What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the library in the environment that you are currently using. It looks like you installed the needed libraries in the Python 2.7 environment but not in 3.6.
Try installing it with `pip3` as follows:

```
pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib
```

Comment: I tried this already but it doesn't seem to work. Already installed sklearn and is able to import it. Script only fails when I'm calling the udf already. Would you have an idea on creating egg files and adding it in to the spark context (sc) variable?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be possible. According to your logs it looks like you are running this on the cloud, right? Could it be that the cluster you are running it on has the library not installed? I'm not really familiar with Cloudera.

Comment: Yes this is on the cloud.